# Laravel Gulp not working after Node update

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, gulp

When running any gulp command in laravel I now get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'internal/fs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:17:20
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/PackyTagliaferro/Sites/Ironhorse/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
```

I tried updating NPM as I read, but still get the error. Current versions:

```
node -v
v7.2.1

npm -v
4.0.5

gulp -v
[11:08:10] CLI version 3.9.0
[11:08:10] Local version 3.9.1
```

How can I get my builds back?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Laravel or gulp problem per se, this is a known error on npm, as you can see in this thread and many other around node's ecosystem:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14232

Comment: Ya, I finally got it to work by deleting all the node_modules and re updating them.